# python xlwt - search for a specific value

Tags: python, search, xlrd

I made a script using xlrd to extract multiple data from multiple cells in multiple excel files, and used xlwt to write these data to a new excel file. In the new excel file I added two additional rows with Formulas that will compute the average and the ttest.
Now I'm trying to add a script that will search through the ttest line and all the values that are under 0.05 to be colored in red. On stackoverflow I found some help but I still receive an error. (For the color, I'm using this source: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt)

Could you please help me ?

Thanks !

```
    from xlwt import *
    style = xlwt.easyxf('font: colour red, bold on')
    wb=xlwt.Workbook()
    wbs=wb.add_sheet("sheet_to_write")
    w=xlrd.open_workbook("file_to_read.xlsx")
    ws=w.sheet_by_name("sheet_to_read")
    c=ws.cell(2,6).value
    wbs.write(46,1,c)
    ... #same as the last two lines, extracting different cells from the sheet_to_red and writing them in the sheet_to_write
    wbs.write(61,1,Formula("TTEST($B3:$B18, $B19:$B57, 2, 2)"))
```

Old code:

```
    for p in range(61):
        p.append(str(sheet.cell(row,col).value))
        if p.value < 0.05:
           cell.color =='22'
```

code 2:

```
    for row in range(61):
      for col in range(wbs.nrows):
        cell=ws.cell(row,col)
            try:
                if float(cell.value) < 0.05:
                  cell.color =='22'
            except ValueError: pass

AttributeError: 'Cell' object has no attribute 'color'
```

code 3:

```
    for row in range(61):
      for col in range(wbs.nrows):
        search=wbs.cell(row,col)
            try:
                if float(search.value) < 0.05:
                  wbs.write(row, col, search.value, style)
            except ValueError: pass
    ERROR:
    AttributeError: 'Worksheet' object has no attribute 'cell',
```

My Conclusion: this method won't work, because xlwt has no attribute cell, or nrows, these attibutes are specific for xlrd. Hence, the only method that would work is to create another file that will use xlrd, search for the specific value, and write it to a new file.
Thanks Pyrce and tmrlvi for your help !

Comment: Can you add the full stack trace (the full output of the exception)? It'd help locating the problem

Comment: Nevermind, I located the error - you call ```p.append``` while ```p``` is a number. What were you trying to achieve in that part of the code?

Comment: Thank you very very much for such a quick answer !! As I understood I wanted to use ".append" to search through all the cell in the row Nr. "61". I'll adapt the next script with the "try". Thanks !

Comment: So the problem in your code is that you write ```for p in range(61):``` instead of ```for row in range(61):``` so you override the ```p``` variable (which I assume was originally a ```list```). I believe @Pyrce answer would solve all issues you have with the code beside that.

Comment: thanks tmrlvi, this is indeed just a list of numbers in a row. I'm adapting Pyrce's code :) Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to append a string to an integer when you just want an assignment. I'm guessing you meant to do something like this:

```
# Generate a color style for writing back into xlwt
xlwt.add_palette_colour("my_color", 0x22)
style = xlwt.easyxf('font: colour my_color;')

for row in range(61):
    cell = input_sheet.cell(row, col)
    try:
       if float(cell.value) < 0.05:
          output_sheet.write(row, col, cell.value, style)
    except ValueError: pass
```

Also as you can see the color assignment is a little different in xlwt than you might expect. You may also need to iterate over all cells and copy them over to the output sheet, or share the same sheet that was read to make this do exactly what you want.

Comment: Hi Pyrce, thank you very much for such a quick answer. I hope I understood correctly your code and changed the "sheet" to "ws" and now I receive the error that "col" is not defined, so I removed the "col", but now I get the error: "try: unexpected indent". Thanks !

Comment: sorry I forgot what is "indent". I'm new in py :) I fixed that.

Comment: Good to hear; you may need to make further changes depending on usecase; i.e. if your number of expected rows changes or is dynamic you may want to use `sheet.nrows` in place of `61`

Comment: Hi Pyrce, thanks for your involvement again. Actually I need specifically that number, because the rows that need to be changed are on the same row in all the sheets. Nevertheless, I still have the problem with color. It seems that cell.color=='22' doesn't work. I found another method, but it still doesn't work. If I put "print 'yes' " instead of color, I receive too many results. Could you please help me with this one ?

Comment: Updated answer to match your request; if this answers your original question you should mark it as the answer on the left box btw -- it'll get people to respond more/faster if your questions get resolved.

Comment: OK! Thanks Pyrce !! Actually I can't use this code in the end, because the values that I'm searching for are all in the new file that was created, so I can't use the line "cell=input_sheet.cell(row,col)", because the line that is being searched is the a new line that is created in the new file. I updated the description. Nevertheless, this method also gives the error: "AttributeError: 'Worksheet' obect has no attribute 'cell' " As I understand this error, this means that xlwt doesn't have the "cell" command", and this command is only present in xlrd.

Comment: Correct, I think you've got what changes you need to make to get this snippet to work in your environment. I made some assumptions about where data was coming from based on your comments, you'll need to replace the read/write lines if those assumptions don't hold. If you get stuck further it probably makes sense to make a new question about those issues. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

`xlwt` supports only `xls` format and below are snippet for writing particular cell value

```
import xlwt
import xlrd
from xlutils.copy import copy

def writedata():
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook("test.xls", "rb")
    wb = copy(workbook)
    w_sheet = wb.get_sheet(0)
    w_sheet.write(2, 4, 'Updated Value') # row, column, value
    wb.save("test.xls")

writedata()
```

Install below package if any error

```
pip install xlwt
pip install xlrd
pip install xlutils
```